# Callback in user-mode from another process, w/o extra thread

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I wonder if  anyone familiar with a synchronization mechanism in user-mode, by which an app can register a "callback" function that would be called when another app signals it ...   **i don't mind the callback to be in an arbitraty thread.**

Suppose i'm having lots of "Worker" processes in parallel, And one wants to notify them of a change (no payloaded data needed),   by which every process will have to do some internal updates.

The immediate approach to this was to create another thread in each of them, and have an infinite loop that waits for a global event and call the callback function right afterwards.    To signal this, one process would only need to signal this global event.

The problem is that i'll have lots of parallel processes in this project, i don't want to add thread*nProcesses to the system just to implement this, even if they're mostly paused.

The current "workaround" i found for this would be to hold my own "dummy" registry key, and every process will "register registery notification callback",  when one app wants to notify the others it will just trigger a write to this key... and windows will callback every process which registered to this notification.

Any other ideas?

Comment: They can check a mutex state, which doesn;t have to be blocking. Or each thread can run a message loop and you can use `SendThreadMessage()`

Comment: I suppose you could design some client/system model with asynchronous pipes. But it would add a lot of complexity to the program. If there is only one single signal and you will not likely expand the IPC beyond that, then perhaps something more simple like your register solution is to prefer.

Comment: Well could you add this functionality to a thread that already exists?  An extra input signal or Windows 'WM_COPYDATA' message?

Answer (score 1):

The nicer solution, which doesn't pollute the registry, would be to use a shared pipe. All workers can connect to the named pipe server, and do an async read. When the server wants to kick the workers, it just writes a byte. This triggers the completion routine of the worker. [Basic example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Still, this notification has the same drawback as most other Windows notifications. If all of your worker threads are running worker code, there's no thread on which your notification can arrive - and you didn't create a special thread for that purpose either. The only solution around that is `CreateRemoteThread`, but that's a very big hammer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the useful ideas,

Eventually, I accidentally came across [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which seems to do just that.

I'm still taking in account @MSalters comment about not having enough free worker threads at a given time since i'm assuming this callback mechanism relies on the same callback mechanism most Win32API does